# how to persistently change sound card

Tags: sound

I have bought a microphone which registers as a sound card, but does not output audio. However, Ubuntu selects my microphone as default output device. Whenever I start Ubuntu, I have to change back the setting by going to Settings -> Sound -> Output -> Output Device.

How can I change the output device so that the setting survives a reboot?

Comment: Does arch wiki help? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples